# Use Firestore rules to limit list fails on array key

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to use Firestore rules to return only documents where the current user has some sort of rights, following the advice given in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access.

However, when I implement the rule I get the dreaded "[code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions" error message which obviously tells me nothing, I was wondering if anyone can spot what is going wrong.

My rules:

```
//Specific project rules - authorised users who appear in the project list
match /documents/{document} {
function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth.uid != null;
  }

function getUser(rsc) {
    return rsc.data.users[request.auth.uid];
  }

function isOneOfUsers(rsc, array) {
  return isSignedIn() && (getUser(rsc) in array);
}

allow list: if isOneOfUsers(resource, ['user','admin']);
```

The data stores the users information in a field on the document (12345 in the example below. The field is of type Object which allows me to put a key (the userid, 76544 in the example below) and a value against it, such as "admin".

My data:

```
documents/12345/users{76544:"admin"}
```

Now when I log on and try to get a list of the documents, I'm expecting to see this document coming back, but I get the error. I can change the function getUser to return "user" and that works, so the problem is somewhere in the evaluation of

```
rsc.data.users[request.auth.uid]
```

I would normally accept that I'm trying something that can't be done but it is a near direct copy of the official docs so I must be missing something!

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is going on: LIST is explicitly not checking every document that it is picking up, rules are not filters etc.

> When writing queries to retrieve documents, keep in mind that security
>   rules are not filters—queries are all or nothing. To save you time and
>   resources, Cloud Firestore evaluates a query against its potential
>   result set instead of the actual field values for all of your
>   documents. If a query could potentially return documents that the
>   client does not have permission to read, the entire request fails.

Therefore, LIST will always return the full list of /documents/, there is nothing you can write in there beyond authorisation rules that will stop it from returning all of them. If this is true, if any malicious actor gets hold of an authentication, they can download the full list of all of your /documents/.

The only sensible approach to this is to lock down any attempt to use LIST (deny all) and keep your list accessible /documents/ against an individual user instead. This seems onerous, but may be the only way of doing it.